# Update  dynamic JSP content

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, struts2

I have Web application. I use Struts2. And I have little JSP:

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
  <body>
    <s:form action="updateForm">
      <s:text name="news.page.main.label"/>
      <s:iterator status="stat" value="news">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><s:property value="title"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="body"/></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </s:iterator>
    </s:form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This page has table with news. For example I have 2 users that open this page and at some time one of them add new row. and I want page of second user update this page for example every 5 minutes.

How can I do this with the help struts2 or JS?

Please give some code for example.

Comment: *"Please give some code for example"*  That is not how SO works.  Show some effort and ask a specific question for better results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are free to use any ajax frameworks, I would say try [Direct Web Remoting](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) and use reverse AJAX.

Comment: The user may only need to refresh the page periodically, not a pretty solution but considering complexity difference, anyways OP consider: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to use a Javascript [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to make an [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) call to your Struts action.

I've given the `jQuery` link here as it makes this type of work a lot easier.